# calculate the (discount = sales price - unit price )

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

How can calculate the (discount = sales price - unit price )
(1-price_unite/list_price)*100

details in image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdoe5.png

Answer (score 0):

Please make one compute function that can compute dicsount according your `sale_price` and `unit_price`.

```
@api.depends('unit_price', 'sale_price')
def compute_discount(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.discount = (1-unit_price/sale_price)/100
```

If I am guessing correctly you need to add this compute method in `purchase.order.line`.